# Borrowing figures from the literature

Tags: publications, citations, thesis, graphics

In my dissertation, I have felt the need to illustrate some ideas with the help of figures and illustrations which I have found available in existing literature. I have borrowed a number of them and I give proper citations and everything. My question is:

Will it be considered a negative point to have multiple borrowed figures from existing publications?

Also, in two cases, I found it hard to rephrase the captions for the images and I just quoted the captions(the proper way). 
Does that look like I am being lazy?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The issue here is not "laziness"; the real issue with reusing figures from the literature is that, without appropriate permissions, you **do not have the right to do so.**

If you reuse a figure in the literature without the appropriate permission from the rights-holders, you are effectively stealing their work, which is not allowed. Therefore, you need to make sure that you have gotten the right to use the figures, and have the proof to back it up if challenged. Normally, for scholarly works such as theses, such rights are routinely granted and cost-free. However, you *need* to check with the publisher (or author of the paper, if she holds publication rights) *before* using the figure. Then, next to the figure you are reproducing, you'll need to have a statement such as "Figure reprinted by permission of *X*," where *X* is the person or institution authorized to grant reproduction rights.

Comment: But those stuff are in the "open" literature. Aren't they? Does that not mean that they are sharing the contents of their work? Like I said, I do acknowledge that the works are not mine and I give the credit.

Comment: Publishing a work is not the same thing as giving people unfettered access to do whatever they like with it. If I cite a figure used in a previous work _that I wrote_, I still have to include a reprint statement acknowledging the original publication. As for who holds the rights, that depends on where it's found. Rights for material in published journals can always be obtained through the publisher; rights for material in places like arXiv are usually through the authors themselves.

Comment: @aeismail: At least in the US, copyright law contains exceptions for "fair use": quoting short passages, making copies for academic use, etc. It could be argued that reproducing a figure would qualify, in which case you actually do have the legal right to use it. But I am not a lawyer.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of fair use restrictions—that's where "appropriate permissions" come into play. If the publisher allows it, just follow their instructions. (I'm sure you could get away with it in a thesis, perhaps, but I think you'd be unlikely to get away with that in a journal article, fair use or no.)

Answer (score 0):

The legal aspects are fuzzy and varies from country to
country. The American Fair Use doctrine may make borrowing
figures (with appropriate citations) permissible in American
copyright law. There may or may not be fair use equivalents in
other jurisdictions.

However, that is not what the question is about.

The question is whether it will be considered "negative" or not. And
the answer is a resounding no. Few authors would mind you borrowing
their figures, *if you appropriately cite them*. Even fewer thesis
readers would care wheter you drew the figures or someone else did
(again, *if you appropriately cite the authors*).

IANAL, this is not legal advice, just my experience with academics.

Comment: Be aware that "fair use" with respect to images is complicated by the fact that an image can carry a lot of information. Much more than a few sentences from  a paper. Just as copying a paragraph or so (with citation) might be problematic, so might copying (or reproducing) an image without explicit permission. The accepted answer has it right, here. And an examination committee reading the thesis might care a great deal if you are sloppy about proper academic conduct.

Comment: American copyright law doesn't care about a work's information content, only about its creativity and originality. But this is about how people would react, not the legality. *My experience* is that nobody cares. If you have different experience (i.e. know of a thesis committee raising a fuss over *appropriately cited* borrowed images) then you can write an interesting answer about that.

Answer (score 0):

As the other answers indicate, permission for re-use is of paramount importance.

So much so that my university's graduate college (separate from the academic department where I did my research) had strict established procedures **AND TIMELINES** relative to graduation dates for demonstrating compliance.  They were somewhat involved.  Without that documentation, the dissertation would simply not be accepted.  The committee had no discretion.

I will note that "fair use" was not an adequate defense *at my particular university*.  Truly open licenses such as Creative Commons were, but still required documentation (although the burden was much lower.)

I strongly urge you to find out if similar guidelines and procedures exist at your institution.  If they do, they will tell exactly what you need to do.

I realize this is not your primary question, but it is important.

As to your primary question:  Dissertations necessarily build on the work that came before it.  We cite papers regularly, and there is no shame or laziness in using some well-designed figures from other sources, provided you have permission.  Likewise captions.